AWS alarms based on metric math - how to add the metric value within the alarm?
I've created a metric and added the Math expression RATE.
Based on the the Math expression, I've created an Alarm.
The question is:
how to use the metric' value within the alarm?
Update:
To be more clear, let's say that the Metric's value is 5.
The RATE expression is set to trigger once the value increases by 1.
and based on the expression I've created the Alarm.
so the next time the metric is up by 1 or more, the alarms is being triggered.
But, at that point i'm not aware of the value, because I only know that it was higher than before.
Hope it makes the question more clear.

What do you mean by "within the alarm"?

Did you read / try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html ? the question is not clear if you created the Alarm based on Math expression you already using it ?!

Might be worth explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Added explanation

Create Lambda function that calls the get_metric_data method.
Create CloudWatch alarm that invokes this created Lambda function when it goes into ALARM state.
import boto3
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

     # Specify your metric details
     namespace = 'AWS/EC2'  # Replace with your metric's namespace
     metric_name = 'CPUUtilization'  # Replace with your metric name
     dimension_name = 'InstanceId'
     dimension_value = 'i-1234567890abcdef0'  # Replace with your actual instance ID or relevant value

     # Define the time range to fetch metric data
     end_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
     start_time = end_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)  # Last 5 minutes

     # Using GetMetricData with a Metric Math expression for RATE
     response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
         MetricDataQueries=[
             {
                 'Id': 'rateQuery',
                 'MetricStat': {
                     'Metric': {
                         'Namespace': namespace,
                         'MetricName': metric_name,
                         'Dimensions': [
                             {
                                 'Name': dimension_name,
                                 'Value': dimension_value
                             }
                         ]
                    },
                     'Period': 60,  # Period for each data point (60 seconds)
                     'Stat': 'Sum'  # Use 'Sum' for cumulative metrics, otherwise adjust
                 },
                 'ReturnData': True
             },
             {
                 'Id': 'rateMathQuery',
                 'Expression': 'RATE(rateQuery)',
                 'Label': 'Rate of Metric',
                 'ReturnData': True
             }
         ],
         StartTime=start_time,
         EndTime=end_time
     )

     # Extract the latest rate value
     rate_results = response.get('MetricDataResults', [])
     if rate_results:
         for result in rate_results:
             if result['Id'] == 'rateMathQuery':
                 # Extract the rate value (you might want the latest or all results)
                 rate_value = result['Values'][-1] if result['Values'] else None
                 if rate_value:
                     print(f"Rate of metric: {rate_value}")
                 else:
                     print("No rate values found.")
     else:
         rate_value = None
         print("No metric data found.")
     return rate_value


I can't try the code, but I upvote the general idea: the alarm event only contains the rate of change, not the absolute values. So whatever reacts to the alarm needs to call GetMetricData to retrieve the absolute values.
